# A Script that will plot an up arrow if current bar closes above previous bar open

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Have been trying to write a script for if a bullish bar
closed above the previous bear bar.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Higher Closes with Arrows", overlay=true)

// Check if close is higher than previous close
closeHigher = barstate.isconfirmed and (close > close[1])

// Create alert condition for higher close
alertcondition(closeHigher, title="Higher Close", message="The current close is higher than the previous close.", shape=alert.shape_arrow_up)

// Plot up arrow when condition is true
plotshape(closeHigher, style=shape.arrowup, color=color.green, size=size.small, location=location.belowbar, text="Up Arrow")
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want an arrow every time a bar closes greater than the previous close, this would do that

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

highClose = close > close[1]
plotshape(highClose, 'Higher Close', shape.arrowup, location.belowbar, color.green)
```